# How to create a dll with the another .cs file in c# using Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, dll

I am using visual studio 2019

I wanna create a dll with the newly added .cs file other than the existing class1.cs in the class library project using .NET framework 4.7.2 in the c# platform

[image: Project structure] from the image you can see that there are 2 classes MathInt.cs and MathFloat.cs

Here MathInt.cs is the default created class Class1.cs, I renamed it and the class MathFloat.cs is added by myself, when i create the dll by building this project in the vs2019, the dll only the functions and properties of the 1st .cs file (i.e) MathInt.cs

How can i create a dll for the 2nd .cs file ie. MathFloat.cs Kindly help me or it is possible to a single dll for both the .cs file in the project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add a second Project to the Solution -- Avoid circular dependencies.

Comment: Normally a project is compiled into an assembly, which becomes an exe-file or dll-file. All classes in that project will be in the assembly. There is not enough information in your question to determine what you have done to exclude one class or even how you determine whether MathFloat is there.

Answer (score 1):

All the classes in the project TestExecClasslibrary will get compiled into one dll.

you get one dll per project. if you want separate dlls you would have to add a second project to your solution.